# When using Mockito @Mock, No qualifying bean of type '(bean name)' available

Tags: spring, mockito

Even though use annotation `@Mock` on a class attribute, but error message of error creating bean is thrown out:

> Error creating bean with name 'DNBSupplierInfoProvider' defined in
> file
> [/Users/i319821/Documents/GitHub/tp-commons/tp-external/build/classes/java/main/com/sap/ariba/trading/partner/commons/spring/external/providers/DNBSupplierInfoProvider.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.sap.ariba.trading.partner.commons.spring.service.impl.HttpConnectionHelper'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

My question is why should I have to create such a bean since I have to use `@Mock`? I expect that Mockito would create a mock object and then it acts as a bean.

```java
package com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.providers;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.TestConfig;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.constants.ExternalSupplierInfoProvider;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.exception.ExternalSupplierException;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.helper.SupplierInfoTestHelper;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.model.CandidatesSearchRequest;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.model.CandidatesSearchResponse;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.model.SupplierDetailSearchRequest;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.providers.mapper.ExternalSupplierMessageMapper;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.external.providers.properties.ExternalSupplierInfoProviderProperties;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.security.oauth.server2lo.OauthServerId;
import com.trading.partner.commons.spring.service.impl.HttpConnectionHelper;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DNBSupplierInfoProviderTest {

  private static final String url = "https://plus.dnb.com";
  private DNBSupplierInfoProvider provider;
  private ExternalSupplierInfoProviderFactory factory;

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Mock
  private HttpConnectionHelper httpConnectionHelper;

  @Mock
  private ExternalSupplierInfoProviderProperties providerProperties;

  @Mock
  private ExternalSupplierMessageMapper externalSupplierMessageMapper;


  private CandidatesSearchResponse candidatesSearchResponse;

  @Mock
  private ExternalSupplierInfoProviderProperties.ProviderProperties dnbProperties;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    candidatesSearchResponse = new CandidatesSearchResponse("1", "10", "10", new ArrayList<>())

    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

    factory = new ExternalSupplierInfoProviderFactory();
    provider = new DNBSupplierInfoProvider(httpConnectionHelper, factory, providerProperties, externalSupplierMessageMapper);
    when(httpConnectionHelper.getAuthHeadersForServer(eq(OauthServerId.DNB))).thenReturn(new HttpHeaders());
    when(httpConnectionHelper.getRestTemplateWithTimeout()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
    when(providerProperties.getPropertiesForProvider(ExternalSupplierInfoProvider.DNB)).thenReturn(dnbProperties);
    when(provider.getClientURL()).thenReturn(url);
    when(provider.getDefaultPageSize()).thenReturn(10);
    when(provider.getDefaultMaxPageSize()).thenReturn(50);
    when(provider.getDetailPath()).thenReturn("/v1/c");
    when(provider.getLookupPath()).thenReturn("/duns");
  }

  @Test
  public void testRegisterWithFactory() {
    provider.register();
    assertNotNull(factory.getExternalDataProvider(ExternalSupplierInfoProvider.DNB.name()));
  }


  @Test
  public void testGetSupplierCandidateList() throws IOException {
    ResponseEntity response = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    when(restTemplate.exchange(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class))).thenReturn(response);
    when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(SupplierInfoTestHelper.createSupplierInfoListResponse());
    when(externalSupplierMessageMapper.searchCriteriaDtoBuilderForExternalSupplier(any(CandidatesSearchRequest.class), any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(SupplierInfoTestHelper.createDNBSearchCriteriaDto());
    when(externalSupplierMessageMapper.transferMatchResultSet(any(String.class), any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(candidatesSearchResponse);
    CandidatesSearchRequest request = SupplierInfoTestHelper.createCandidatesSearchRequest();
    assertNotNull(provider.getSupplierCandidateList(request));
  }

  @Test(expected = ExternalSupplierException.class)
  public void testGetSupplierCandidateListWithNoDataFound() throws ExternalSupplierException {
    HttpClientErrorException exception = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    doThrow(exception).when(restTemplate).exchange(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class));
    CandidatesSearchRequest request = SupplierInfoTestHelper.createCandidatesSearchRequest();
    assertNotNull(provider.getSupplierCandidateList(request));
  }

  @Test(expected = ExternalSupplierException.class)
  public void testGetSupplierCandidateListWithInternalError() throws ExternalSupplierException {
    HttpServerErrorException exception = new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    doThrow(exception).when(restTemplate).exchange(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class));
    CandidatesSearchRequest request = SupplierInfoTestHelper.createCandidatesSearchRequest();
    assertNotNull(provider.getSupplierCandidateList(request));
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetSupplierDetail() throws IOException {
    ResponseEntity response = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    when(restTemplate.exchange(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class))).thenReturn(response);
    when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(SupplierInfoTestHelper.createSupplierInfoResponse());
    when(externalSupplierMessageMapper.convertToExternalSupplierInfoFromJsonObject(any(JSONObject.class), any(Boolean.class))).thenReturn(SupplierInfoTestHelper.createDNBSupplierDetail());
    SupplierDetailSearchRequest request = SupplierInfoTestHelper.createSupplierDetailSearchRequest();
    assertNotNull(provider.getSupplierDetail(request));
  }

  @Test(expected = ExternalSupplierException.class)
  public void testGetSupplierDetailWithNoDataFound() throws ExternalSupplierException {
    HttpClientErrorException exception = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    doThrow(exception).when(restTemplate).exchange(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class));
    SupplierDetailSearchRequest request = SupplierInfoTestHelper.createSupplierDetailSearchRequest();
    assertNotNull(provider.getSupplierDetail(request));
  }

  @Test(expected = ExternalSupplierException.class)
  public void testGetSupplierDetailWithInternalError() throws ExternalSupplierException {
    HttpServerErrorException exception = new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    doThrow(exception).when(restTemplate).exchange(any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class));
    SupplierDetailSearchRequest request = SupplierInfoTestHelper.createSupplierDetailSearchRequest();
    assertNotNull(provider.getSupplierDetail(request));
  }

}
```

Comment: use `@MockBean` as stated in the documentation.

Comment: The mock instances created via `@Mock` are not part of Spring's application context. Based on the stack trace, when Spring attempted to create `DNBSupplierInfoProvider`, it failed to find an instance of `HttpConnectionHelper`. While the test is aware that it has a mocked instance, the Spring context is unaware of it. As @M. Deinum mentioned, using `@MockBean` defines a mock and also adds it into the context. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html